# Cyclic inheritance in Activity implementing Fragment's interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using an interface to pass data from a fragment to the parent activity. However, after implementing the interface in the Activity, cyclic inheritance is introduced. Please suggest possible solutions?

The essential bits of code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstActivity.FirstFragment.PassSituationData {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //.......

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "A");
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment(), "B");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataPass(String nameText) {
        Log.d("data",nameText);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


    public static class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

        public SecondFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }

    }

    public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

        PassSituationData dataListener;


        public FirstFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public interface PassSituationData {
            public void onDataPass(String nameText);
        }


        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity a) {
            super.onAttach(a);
            try {
                dataListener = (PassSituationData) a;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(a.toString() + " must implement PassSituationData");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_situation, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == Constants.SITUATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (data != null) {
                    String nameText = data.getStringExtra("name");
                    dataListener.onDataPass(nameText);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: Cyclic inheritance involving 'com.example.FirstActivity'

Comment: move the interface in its own compilation unit (aks a separate file)

Comment: ok. i misunderstood the situation.

Comment: Move the Fragment out of that activity or move the interface in its separate java class

Comment: why would you create the Fragments as static nested inner classes? Put them as classes outside the main activity.

Comment: i just had to move the interface to a seperate file. i don't think, in my implementation, the static nested fragments are causing the problem. Thanks for the insight, btw. thanks @Blackbelt

Answer (score 0):

Firsly in your fragment implement method onDetach, 
inside clear reference in dataListener

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();        
    dataListener = null;
}
```

You are storing reference to activity (as dataListener is your activity casted to interface), you need to clear that when no longer needed.

And one more thing please don't make fragments and adapters as inner classes :)